# Setup custom launcher with paths as a param values in VS Code (Flask - certificate path)

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

There is an example in [Visual Studio Code python setup tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) it is shown how to setup `Flask`. My problem starts when I try to provide self-signed certificate paths. I've tried to add following configuration:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--debugger",
            "--no-reload",
            "--host",
            "0.0.0.0",
            "--port",
            "4443",
            "--key",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\viberbot\\key.pem",
            "--cert",
            "${workspaceFolder}\\viberbot\\certificate.pem"
        ],
        "jinja": true
    },
```

I've tried to provide key/cert as:

- C:\\FULL_PATH\\TO\\FILE
- C:/FULL_PATH/TO/FILE
- 'C:\\FULL_PATH\\TO\\FILE'
- \"C:\\FULL_PATH\\TO\\FILE\"

and I always getting one of these error messages:
`Error: Invalid value for "--key": "--cert" must also be specified.`
or `Error: Invalid value for "--key": File ""E:\Docs\learn_py\viberbot\key.pem"" does not exist.`

This is the exact command generated by `VS Code` extension:

> cd e:\Docs\learn_py && cmd /C "set "FLASK_APP=app.py" && set
>   "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" &&
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
>   c:\Users\user.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.2.5558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py
>   --default --client --host localhost --port 50573 -m flask run --debugger --no-reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4443 --key E:\Docs\learn_py\viberbot\key.pem --cert
>   E:\Docs\learn_py\viberbot\certificate.pem " Usage: python -m flask run
>   [OPTIONS] Try "python -m flask run --help" for help.
>
> Error: Invalid value for "--key": "--cert" must also be specified.

UPDATE: after making the change suggested by Brett I've started to get another error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "app".
```

I've tried to change `app.py` to `${workspaceFolder}\\viberbot\\app.py` or providing a path like `/E/path/viberbot/app.py` and it didn't work.

UPDATE2: I needed to do `"FLASK_APP": "viberbot\\app.py"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because the example in the tutorial is out of date compared to the default that VS Code provides. Try:

```
{
            "name": "Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload",
                "--cert",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\viberbot\\certificate.pem",
                "--key",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\viberbot\\key.pem"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
```

Comment: Error: Invalid value for "--cert": File "E:\Docs\learn_py\viberbot\certificate.pem" does not exist.

Comment: That's unfortunately coming from Flask so I'm not able to help anymore. Flask obviously doesn't think that file exists, so maybe a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Cert argument must be specified before key.
So the actual fix is to change the order of the arguments.

```
flask run -h :: -p 443 --cert cert.pem --key key.pem
# won't work: flask run -h :: -p 443 --key key.pem --cert cert.pem
```

Actual for v1.1.4, not sure if this fixed in 2+.